# 1 installation of codeigniter removes sessions of other installation

Tags: codeigniter

I am developing a site which has an admin panel too. The structure of my website is following.

```
application(front site)
  controllers
  views
  models 
admin
  application
    controllers
    views
    models
```

The problem occurs when I login to admin and on the same time I open front end in the same browser. It removes session for admin so admin logouts after opening front end.

Comment: If you use codeigniter 2.x , it uses cookies instead of native session, maybe you should give them different encryption key to solve this problem. But codeigniter 3.x uses native session, it should works right. Give it a try and let me know what is the result.